# Sphinx not update until service restart?

Tags: windows, sphinx

I have Sphinx running as a Service on Windows Server 2003

I also have the ff cronjob running every 2 min to update the index:

```
C:\sphinx\bin\indexer.exe -c C:\sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf --rotate delta
```

and every 12 h:

```
C:\sphinx\bin\indexer.exe -c C:\sphinx\bin\sphinx.conf --rotate --all
```

However somehow the task every 1m ran, but there was no update on my website at all. The reindex run successfully.

The only time it update on website is to have my service restart.

What could be the problem here? I could not create a cron job to restart the service just for update. Since it could seriously affect searching operation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the setting `preopen_indexes` to 0 (zero).

I had the same problem. If you run the searchd service as debug, you can see it gives a 'Broken pipe' error. This is caused because the process has his index files always open.
If you set the `preopen_indexes` to 0, it will only open if you search (Yes, it's a bit slower than opening it once)

I found the answer at the sphinx forum, http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=572

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I was testing it and it really work. The problem is that i have a preopen = 1 in one of my index. Now change it back to 0 and it work just fine.